# Javascript Cookie: Cookie can't be retrieved from the page that set it in IE

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm having a weird issue setting and getting a cookie in IE9. This works fine in Firefox, Chrome, etc.

I'm using a simple javascript method to set a cookie. I'm setting the path to be "/Phoenix". On other browsers (i.e FF & Chrome) I have no problems retrieving the value of the cookie, whether the URL path is "/Phoenix", "/Phoenix/", etc...

However in IE (specifically 9 but it behaves identically in older versions too) I cannot retrieve the cookie when my URL path is "/Phoenix" - which is exactly what it is set to, if I change the URL path to "/Phoenix/" it will work fine.

When I use the developer tools and inspect the document element when the URL path is "/Phoenix" the cookie is not there, however, when I change the URL path to "/Phoenix/" it is present.

Here is my getting and setting functions:

```
var BasicUtils = new function ()
{
    this.GetCookie = function(c_name)
    {
        var i, x, y, ARRcookies = document.cookie.split(";");
        for (i = 0; i < ARRcookies.length; i++)
        {
            x = ARRcookies[i].substr(0, ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
            y = ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=") + 1);
            x = x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
            if (x == c_name)
            {
                return unescape(y);
            }
        }
    }

    this.SetCookie = function(c_name, value, exdays, path)
    {
        var exdate = new Date();
        exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
        var c_value = escape(value) + ((exdays == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString());
        document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value + '; path=' + path;
    }
}
```

Here is where it is set:

```
$(window).unload(function ()
{
    var userStateCookie = UserStateManager.GetUserState();
    BasicUtils.SetCookie(mainPage.CookieName, $.toJSON(userStateCookie), 1825, mainPage.CookiePath);
});
```

Here is where it is loaded:

```
var cookieString = BasicUtils.GetCookie(this.CookieName);
```

In all cases the path is being set to "/Phoenix". The cookie names are the same, it just isn't found in the document.cookie when I inspect or watch that.

Again this only seems to be an IE issue. Could it be a security setting somewhere? Any suggestions?

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Post your code please.  The issue is obviously related to the specifics of your code as cookies work just fine in IE so we need to see your exact code.

Comment: I hope that helps clarify the problem. I feel like I'm banging my head against a wall. It works fine in other browsers using the identical logic...